# How to prevent raw github tokens from expiring

Tags: github, https, token, access-token

I want to fetch a file from a github repository and read it from my application using http request url.

I tried using the below http url.,

Example:
https://raw.github.xxx.com/sample-repo/config-details/master/conf/application-dev.conf?token=ABAD5JUZ7O84U7CIKEU4MGY5UWJU6

It worked well, but after a week the token got expired. So I am getting "404: Not found" when I try to fetch the file.

Is there any way to prevent the token from expiring or any better solution to solve this problem?

**Update:**

Actually I am trying to implement a remote config server in play framework. 
I am using play-rconf-http (a library which helps to fetch a config file hosted in a http server)

I will set the remote file url in my app's config file as below,
remote-configuration.http.url = "https://raw.github.xxx.com/sample-repo/config-details/master/conf/application-dev.conf?token=ABAD5JUZ7O84U7CIKEU4MGY5UWJU6"

So while my server starts it will fetch the file from the remote server and load the configuration.

It was working as I expected, but after few days the tokens are getting expired. So I need to solve it.

Comment: In short, you can't prevent them from expiring. This might be an example of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/304955). Could you update the post with what you are trying to accomplish - this API is likely your best approach but depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @osowskit I have updated the actual problem, please check now.